# document.getElementById vs $("#something")

Tags: jquery, dom

Would you like to explain what is different between

```
document.getElementById("something")
```

and

```
$("#something")
```

I am trying to upload a document using ajax and I realised that

```
var upl = document.getElementById('uplFile');
    console.log(upl.files);
```

returning an object but

```
var upl = $('#uplFile');
    console.log(upl.files);
```

returning "undefined"

Please, explain a diffrerence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you mean the difference between:

```
document.getElementById("something")
```

and

```
$('#something')
```

The first one will return the DOM element with the specified id, or null.

The second one will return a jQuery object, which will either contain the DOM element with the specified id, or be an empty jQuery object (length = 0).

As the jQuery function returns a jQuery object and not an element, you have to get the element out of the jQuery object to access the element properties:

```
var upl = $('#uplFile');
console.log(upl[0].files);
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `getElementById('id')` return an HTML DOM element, while `$('id')` returns a DOM element wrapped by a jQuery object.

So the difference between your two examples is that you're referencing a property of the returned object.  Obviosly, the jQuery object doesn't have a files property, while the DOM element does.